# Symfony validation registration form. I got this error data.password Password cannot be empty

Tags: php, laravel, symfony

i got this error when i submited my registration form in symfony data.password Password cannot be empty. I got all data from all other fields except the email field

Symfony validation registration form. I got this error data.password Password cannot be empty

**Here is my user.php entity with validation constraint**

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Cocur\Slugify\Slugify;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Types;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

#[ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks]
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: UserRepository::class)]
#[UniqueEntity(fields: ['email'], message: 'Il existe déjà un compte avec cet email')]
class User implements UserInterface, PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[Assert\Email(message: "L'email '{{ value }}' n'est pas valide")]
    #[Assert\NotBlank(message: "L'email ne peut pas être vide")]
    #[Assert\Length(max: 100, maxMessage: "L'email ne peut pas faire plus de 180 caractères")]
    #[ORM\Column(length: 100, unique: true)]
    private ?string $email = null;

    #[ORM\Column]
    private array $roles = [];

    /**
     * @var string The hashed password
     */
    #[ORM\Column]
    #[Assert\Length(min: 8, minMessage: "Le mot de passe doit faire au moins 8 caractères")]
    #[Assert\NotBlank(message: "Le mot de passe ne peut pas être vide")]
    #[Assert\Regex(pattern: '/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*\W).{8,}$/', message: "Le mot de passe doit contenir au moins 1 majuscule, 1 minuscule, 1 chiffre et 1 caractère spécial")]
    private ?string $password = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    #[Assert\Length(min: 2, max: 100, minMessage: "Le prénom doit faire au moins 2 caractères", maxMessage: "Le prénom ne peut pas faire plus de 100 caractères")]
    #[Assert\NotBlank(message: "Le prénom ne peut pas être vide")]
    #[Assert\Regex(pattern: '/^[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ]+([-\'\s][a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ]+)*$/', message: "Le prénom n'est pas valide")]
    private ?string $firstName = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    #[Assert\Length(min: 2, max: 100, minMessage: "Le nom doit faire au moins 2 caractères", maxMessage: "Le nom ne peut pas faire plus de 100 caractères")]
    #[Assert\NotBlank(message: "Le nom ne peut pas être vide")]
    #[Assert\Regex(pattern: '/^[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ]+([-\'\s][a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ]+)*$/', message: "Le nom n'est pas valide")]
    private ?string $lastName = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    #[Assert\Length(min: 50, max: 255, minMessage: "L'introduction doit faire au moins 50 caractères", maxMessage: "L'introduction ne peut pas faire plus de 255 caractères")]
    #[Assert\NotBlank(message: "L'introduction ne peut pas être vide")]
    private ?string $introduction = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::TEXT)]
    #[Assert\NotBlank(message: "La présentation ne peut pas être vide")]
    #[Assert\Length(min: 100, minMessage: "La présentation doit faire au moins 100 caractères")]
    private ?string $presentation = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    private ?string $slug = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    #[Assert\Length(min: 2, max: 200, minMessage: "L'adresse doit faire au moins 2 caractères", maxMessage: "L'adresse ne peut pas faire plus de 200 caractères")]
    #[Assert\NotBlank(message: "L'adresse ne peut pas être vide")]
    private ?string $address = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    #[Assert\Length(min: 2, max: 100, minMessage: "La ville doit faire au moins 2 caractères", maxMessage: "La ville ne peut pas faire plus de 100 caractères")]
    #[Assert\NotBlank(message: "La ville ne peut pas être vide")]
    private ?string $city = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    #[Assert\NotBlank(message: "La ville ne peut pas être vide")]
    #[Assert\Length(min: 5, max: 5, exactMessage: "Le code postal doit faire 5 caractères")]
    #[Assert\Regex(pattern: '/^[0-9]{5}$/', message: "Le code postal n'est pas valide")]
    private ?string $postalCode = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    private ?string $country = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255, nullable: true)]
    private ?string $profilPicture = null;

    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?\DateTimeImmutable $createdAt = null;

    #[ORM\Column(nullable: true)]
    private ?\DateTimeImmutable $updatedAt = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    #[Assert\Length(min: 10, max: 10, exactMessage: "Le numéro de téléphone doit faire 10 caractères")]
    #[Assert\Regex(pattern: '/^[0-9]{10}$/', message: "Le numéro de téléphone n'est pas valide")]
    #[Assert\NotBlank(message: "Le numéro de téléphone ne peut pas être vide")]
    #[Assert\NotEqualTo(value: '0000000000', message: "Le numéro de téléphone n'est pas valide")]
    #[Assert\NotEqualTo(value: '1111111111', message: "Le numéro de téléphone n'est pas valide")]
    #[Assert\NotEqualTo(value: '2222222222', message: "Le numéro de téléphone n'est pas valide")]
    #[Assert\NotEqualTo(value: '3333333333', message: "Le numéro de téléphone n'est pas valide")]
    #[Assert\NotEqualTo(value: '4444444444', message: "Le numéro de téléphone n'est pas valide")]
    #[Assert\NotEqualTo(value: '5555555555', message: "Le numéro de téléphone n'est pas valide")]
    #[Assert\NotEqualTo(value: '6666666666', message: "Le numéro de téléphone n'est pas valide")]
    #[Assert\NotEqualTo(value: '7777777777', message: "Le numéro de téléphone n'est pas valide")]
    #[Assert\NotEqualTo(value: '8888888888', message: "Le numéro de téléphone n'est pas valide")]
    #[Assert\NotEqualTo(value: '9999999999', message: "Le numéro de téléphone n'est pas valide")]
    #[Assert\NotEqualTo(value: '1234567890', message: "Le numéro de téléphone n'est pas valide")]
    #[Assert\NotEqualTo(value: '0987654321', message: "Le numéro de téléphone n'est pas valide")]
    #[Assert\NotEqualTo(value: '0123456789', message: "Le numéro de téléphone n'est pas valide")]
    #[Assert\NotEqualTo(value: '9876543210', message: "Le numéro de téléphone n'est pas valide")]
    private ?string $phone = null;

    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'author', targetEntity: Ad::class)]
    private Collection $ads;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->ads = new ArrayCollection();
    }


    #[ORM\PrePersist] // Pour que cette méthode soit appelée avant la persistance
    #[ORM\PreUpdate] // Pour que cette méthode soit appelée avant la mise à jour
    public function initializeSlugAndCreated(): void
    {
        if (empty($this->slug)) {
            $slugify = new Slugify();
            $this->slug = $slugify->slugify($this->firstName . '-' . $this->lastName);
        }

        if (empty($this->createdAt)) {
            $this->createdAt = new \DateTimeImmutable();
        }
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getEmail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail(string $email): self
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * A visual identifier that represents this user.
     *
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getUserIdentifier(): string
    {
        return (string) $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getRoles(): array
    {
        $roles = $this->roles;
        // guarantee every user at least has ROLE_USER
        $roles[] = 'ROLE_USER';

        return array_unique($roles);
    }

    public function setRoles(array $roles): self
    {
        $this->roles = $roles;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @see PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
     */
    public function getPassword(): string
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function setPassword(string $password): self
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
        // If you store any temporary, sensitive data on the user, clear it here
        // $this->plainPassword = null;
    }

    public function getFirstName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->firstName;
    }

    public function setFirstName(string $firstName): self
    {
        $this->firstName = $firstName;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getLastName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->lastName;
    }

    public function setLastName(string $lastName): self
    {
        $this->lastName = $lastName;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getIntroduction(): ?string
    {
        return $this->introduction;
    }

    public function setIntroduction(string $introduction): self
    {
        $this->introduction = $introduction;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPresentation(): ?string
    {
        return $this->presentation;
    }

    public function setPresentation(string $presentation): self
    {
        $this->presentation = $presentation;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getSlug(): ?string
    {
        return $this->slug;
    }

    public function setSlug(string $slug): self
    {
        $this->slug = $slug;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAddress(): ?string
    {
        return $this->address;
    }

    public function setAddress(string $address): self
    {
        $this->address = $address;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCity(): ?string
    {
        return $this->city;
    }

    public function setCity(string $city): self
    {
        $this->city = $city;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPostalCode(): ?string
    {
        return $this->postalCode;
    }

    public function setPostalCode(string $postalCode): self
    {
        $this->postalCode = $postalCode;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCountry(): ?string
    {
        return $this->country;
    }

    public function setCountry(string $country): self
    {
        $this->country = $country;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getProfilPicture(): ?string
    {
        return $this->profilPicture;
    }

    public function setProfilPicture(?string $profilPicture): self
    {
        $this->profilPicture = $profilPicture;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCreatedAt(): ?\DateTimeImmutable
    {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }

    public function setCreatedAt(\DateTimeImmutable $createdAt): self
    {
        $this->createdAt = $createdAt;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getUpdatedAt(): ?\DateTimeImmutable
    {
        return $this->updatedAt;
    }

    public function setUpdatedAt(?\DateTimeImmutable $updatedAt): self
    {
        $this->updatedAt = $updatedAt;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPhone(): ?string
    {
        return $this->phone;
    }

    public function setPhone(string $phone): self
    {
        $this->phone = $phone;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, Ad>
     */
    public function getAds(): Collection
    {
        return $this->ads;
    }

    public function addAd(Ad $ad): self
    {
        if (!$this->ads->contains($ad)) {
            $this->ads->add($ad);
            $ad->setAuthor($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeAd(Ad $ad): self
    {
        if ($this->ads->removeElement($ad)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($ad->getAuthor() === $this) {
                $ad->setAuthor(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

**Here my registrationFormType.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\IsTrue;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Length;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FileType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\EmailType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CountryType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CheckboxType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\PasswordType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\RepeatedType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;

class RegistrationFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('email',EmailType::class, [
                'label' => false,
                'attr' => [
                    'placeholder' => 'Entrez votre email',
                    'class' => 'form-control mb-3',
                ]
            ])
            ->add('firstName',TextType::class, [
                'label' => false,
                'attr' => [
                    'placeholder' => 'Entrez votre prénom',
                    'class' => 'form-control mb-3',
                ]
            ])
            ->add('lastName',TextType::class, [
                'label' => false,
                'attr' => [
                    'placeholder' => 'Entrez votre nom',
                    'class' => 'form-control mb-3',
                ]
            ])
            ->add('address',TextType::class, [
                'label' => false,
                'attr' => [
                    'placeholder' => 'Entrez votre adresse',
                    'class' => 'form-control mb-3',
                ]
            ])
            ->add('city',TextType::class, [
                'label' => false,
                'attr' => [
                    'placeholder' => 'Entrez votre ville',
                    'class' => 'form-control mb-3',
                ]
            ])
            ->add('postalCode',TextType::class, [
                'label' => false,
                'attr' => [
                    'placeholder' => 'Entrez votre code postal',
                    'class' => 'form-control mb-3',
                ]
            ])
            ->add('country',CountryType::class, [
                'label' => false,
                'attr' => [
                    'placeholder' => 'Entrez votre pays',
                    'class' => 'form-control mb-3',
                ],
                'preferred_choices' => ['FR', 'BE', 'CH', 'LU'],
            ])
            ->add('phone',TextType::class, [
                'label' => false,
                'attr' => [
                    'placeholder' => 'Entrez votre numéro de téléphone',
                    'class' => 'form-control mb-3',
                ]
            ])
            ->add('introduction',TextareaType::class, [
                'label' => false,
                'attr' => [
                    'placeholder' => 'Entrez une courte introduction',
                    'class' => 'form-control mb-3',
                    'rows' => 3,
                ]
            ])
            ->add('presentation',TextareaType::class, [
                'label' => false,
                'attr' => [
                    'placeholder' => 'Faites une présentation de vous même et de votre activité !',
                    'class' => 'form-control mb-3',
                    'rows' => 5,
                ]
            ])
            ->add('profilPicture',FileType::class, [
                'label' => false,
                'attr' => [
                    'placeholder' => 'Entrez votre avatar',
                    'class' => 'form-control mb-3',
                ],
                'required' => false,
            ])
            ->add('agreeTerms', CheckboxType::class, [
                'mapped' => false,
                'constraints' => [
                    new IsTrue([
                        'message' => 'Vous devez accepter nos conditions.',
                    ]),
                ],
            ])
            ->add('plainPassword', RepeatedType::class, [
                // instead of being set onto the object directly,
                // this is read and encoded in the controller
                'type' => PasswordType::class,
                'mapped' => false,
                'attr' => ['autocomplete' => 'new-password'],
                'first_options'  => [
                    'label' => false,
                    'attr' => [
                        'placeholder' => 'Entrez votre mot de passe',
                        'class' => 'form-control mb-3',
                    ]
                ],
                'second_options' => [
                    'label' => false,
                    'attr' => [
                        'placeholder' => 'Confirmez votre mot de passe',
                        'class' => 'form-control mb-3',
                    ]
                ],
            ])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => User::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

**Here my registrationController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\User;
use App\Form\RegistrationFormType;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\PasswordHasher\Hasher\UserPasswordHasherInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Contracts\Translation\TranslatorInterface;

class RegistrationController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/register', name: 'app_register')]
    public function register(Request $request, UserPasswordHasherInterface $userPasswordHasher, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager): Response
    {
        $user = new User();
        $form = $this->createForm(RegistrationFormType::class, $user);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

            dd($form->get('plainPassword')->getData());
            
            // encode the plain password
            $user->setPassword(
                $userPasswordHasher->hashPassword(
                    $user,
                    $form->get('plainPassword')->getData()
                )
            );

            $image = $form['profilPicture']->getData();
            if ($image) {
                $fichierUrl = md5(uniqid()) . '' . bin2hex(random_bytes(15)) . '' . time() . '.' . $image->guessExtension();

                // On copie le fichier dans le dossier uploads
                $image->move(
                    $this->getParameter('profile_user_directory'),
                    $fichierUrl
                );

                // On stocke l'image dans la base de données (son nom)
                $imagePath = '/assets/images/uploads/ad/' . $fichierUrl;
                $user->setProfilPicture($fichierUrl);
            } else {
                $user->setProfilPicture('default.svg');
            }


            $entityManager->persist($user);
            $entityManager->flush();
            // do anything else you need here, like send an email

            $this->addFlash('success', 'Votre compte a bien été créé !');

            // Vider le formulaire
            $user = new User();
            $form = $this->createForm(RegistrationFormType::class, $user);

            return $this->redirectToRoute('app_account');
        }

        return $this->render('registration/register.html.twig', [
            'registrationForm' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }
}
```

**Here my template twig**

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Inscription -
    {{ parent() }}
{% endblock %}


{% block body %}

    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-9 m-auto">

                <h1 class="text-center my-5">Inscrivez-vous <span class="text-muted text-capitalize">C'est simple et rapide</span></h1>

                {{ form_start(registrationForm) }}
                {{ form_row(registrationForm.firstName) }}
                {{ form_row(registrationForm.lastName) }}
                {{ form_row(registrationForm.email) }}
                {{ form_row(registrationForm.plainPassword, {
            label: 'Password'
        }) }}
                
                {{ form_row(registrationForm.phone) }}
                {{ form_row(registrationForm.address) }}
                {{ form_row(registrationForm.city) }}
                {{ form_row(registrationForm.postalCode) }}
                {{ form_row(registrationForm.country) }}
                {{ form_row(registrationForm.introduction) }}
                {{ form_row(registrationForm.presentation) }}
                {{ form_row(registrationForm.profilPicture) }}

                {{ form_row(registrationForm.agreeTerms) }}
                {{ form_label(registrationForm.agreeTerms, "J'accepte les termes et conditions") }}

                <div class="d-grid gap-2 col-6 mx-auto">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary rounded">S'inscrire</button>
                </div>
                {{ form_end(registrationForm) }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


{% endblock %}
```

Do you have any idea where the problem is that I can't recover the password? when i dump $form in controller , i have everything but password

Comment: There's `NotBlank`  constraint on the password field, I would assume that's the reason you cannot submit the form without that field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your user model, there is a $password property that you add rules including not blank.

But in your RegistrationFormType, you don't add password input. You add plainPassword instead

So in your User class, you can consider change the name of $password property to $plainPassword:

```
class User implements UserInterface, PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
{
   /**
     * @var string The hashed password
     */
    #[ORM\Column]
    #[Assert\Length(min: 8, minMessage: "Le mot de passe doit faire au moins 8 caractères")]
    #[Assert\NotBlank(message: "Le mot de passe ne peut pas être vide")]
    #[Assert\Regex(pattern: '/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*\W).{8,}$/', message: "Le mot de passe doit contenir au moins 1 majuscule, 1 minuscule, 1 chiffre et 1 caractère spécial")]
    private ?string $plainPassword = null;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. All is ok now